# GuiApplication Children empty

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I need some help understanding why the `Children` property of `GuiApplication` object is empty.

I do something like:

```
var engine = SapRot.GetType().InvokeMember("GetScriptingEngine", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, SapRot, null);
var connection = (engine as GuiApplication).OpenConnection(connectionString);
var session = connection.Children.ElementAt(0) as GuiSession;
```

All those objects (engine, connection and session) are COM objects, which I'm not really familiar with, and `connection.Children` is always empty. However, when running the application, I see it indeed connects to the SAP Logon and to the SAP application.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issues (yes, plural. There were two issues in two different customers).

In one customer, it was because the SAP server wasn't allowing scripting, which you can solve by [setting sapgui/user_scripting to TRUE when you run a rz11 command](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/08/introduction-to-sap-gui-scripting/).

In the other customer, it was because of the SAP version. Apparently SAP 6 doesn't support scripting the way it's done in my question's description.